# What is the particular $Y_p$ for the general solution $y''+y=6\sin x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

In this case, We set
$Y_p=Cx(A\cos x+B\sin x)$ beacuse of $D= \pm i$
then, $$Y_p''=2C(-A\sin x+B\cos x)+Cx(-A\cos x-B\sin x)$$
$$Y_p''+Y_p=2C(-A\sin x+B\cos x)=6\sin x$$
So $AC=-3$, BC=0, if C=1,
then we have $Y_p=--3xsin x$ .However...
According to the reference, $$Y_p=-3x\cos x$$ but I don't understand why.

Comment: You are mistaking $y''+y'$ for $y''+y$. $\sin$ and $\cos$ are not solutions of the homogeneous equation.

Comment: You said $B=0$. Note that your $y_p$ had $A\cos x + B\color{red}{\sin x}$ (i.e. *$B$ is the coefficient of $\sin x$ in the particular solution*). That means the $\sin x$ term is the one that will disappear. Also, you may want to double check your $C$ value. Assuming the ODE is $y'' + y =6\sin x$, the general solution is [here](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y"+%2B+y+%3D+6sin%28x%29).

Comment: @ I think both answers are wrong. Did you type the DE wrongly?

Comment: By the way, in general for the particular solution like this, you don't need to bother with the $C$, i.e. you can just use $y_p = x(A\cos x + B\sin x)$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Please read the DE correctly. LHS is $y''+y'$, not $y''+y$.

Comment: I know. I was assuming it was a typo because OP's working out for the particular solution did things based on $y''+ y$.

Comment: I corrected them as you said. Sorry...

Answer (score 1):

y = A xsin x + Bxcos x

y' = Asin x + Bcos x - B xsin x + Axcos x

y'' = -2Bsin x + 2Acos x - Axsin x + Bxcos x
y''+y = -2Bsinx + 2Acosx = -6sin x

$B = -\frac {1}{2}*6=-3 , A = 0$

$y = c_1sint + c_2cosx -3xcosx$

$y(0) = 6sin0=C_2 = 0$

$y'(0) = C_1 = 0$

$y = -3xcosx$